# Scan PHP array using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays

```
$namesSelect = "SELECT username FROM users";  
$names = mysql_query($namesSelect);
$nameCheck = mysql_fetch_array($names)
```

This selects all names from the users table and sets them to the array $names.

What I need to do is look through this array using javascript, to find if the name that the user has entered matches. I have no idea where to start with this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry but what you have said just makes no sense

Comment: How many users are expected to be in the database? Is this less than 100, or maybe rather more than 100,000?

Comment: You need to use Ajax. Your javascript function would call a PHP page (with ajax) that runs the MySql query and returns the results. Then you can process those results with javascript.

Comment: Could you please at least search the internet for what Javascript is before asking here? The simple answer is: not possible, since PHP is server-side and javascript is client-side. (Except if you're trying to go really exotic, but that doesnt seem to be the case.)

Comment: This is impossible. Read up on AJAX.

Answer (score 4):

You're approaching this wrong.

Have the user submit the name, then check it with PHP.

You can check it by placing the name the user has entered to the `WHERE` clause of your query.

Comment: Or, rather, have MySQL scan it `WHERE username = 'Joe'`.